# How can I see the aggregated logs for a Spark standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark, logging, distributed-computing

With Spark running over Yarn, I could simply use yarn -logs -applicationId appId to see the aggregated log, after a Spark job is finished. What is the equivalent method for a Spark standalone cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Via the [Web Interface](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#monitoring-and-logging):

> Spark’s standalone mode offers a web-based user interface to monitor
>   the cluster. The master and each worker has its own web UI that shows
>   cluster and job statistics. By default you can access the web UI for
>   the master at port 8080. The port can be changed either in the
>   configuration file or via command-line options.
>
> In addition, detailed log output for each job is also written to the
>   work directory of each slave node (SPARK_HOME/work by default). You
>   will see two files for each job, stdout and stderr, with all output it
>   wrote to its console.

Please find more information in [Monitoring and Instrumentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html).

Comment: I can see the master UI, but when I click on a worker link, I can't connect to it. Is there any setting needed to enable that in Spark?

Comment: @pythonic did you checked if you can connect to that worker IP? Probably you need a tunnel to that worker to see the UI through the link...